# What is the true fundamental 'stuff' of physics?

Tags: energy, time, education, space

It seems to me that most if not all of the publications and the institutional education of physics 'jump in' and start describing detailed phenomena without spending too much time describing and relating the more fundamental concepts that give rise to all these details. And what time is spent on the fundamental 'stuff' is often vague and confusing. What's more, physics education seems to describe all the things we do know (or else believe we know) and pays little attention to the things we don't know. And if we don't admit what we don't know then students tend to fill in the gaps with false ideas.

So then what is the true fundamental 'stuff' of physics? And how do these fundamental things relate to one another in a fundamental manner before delving in to all the wonderful details we discuss here daily in the StackExchange?

After some thought I believe the fundamental things are: **Space** - **Time** - and **Energy**

Why not matter? - because energy is a more fundamental form of matter (sort of like 'condensed' energy)

Why not Space-time?  rather than separately space and time? - I guess I'm not sure - although they are closely intertwined I believe they are distinct.

Perhaps my 'gaps' in learning have lead me to an imprecise world view?

Comment: Define *fundamental stuff*.

Comment: I fully subscribe to the complain that "most if not all of the publications and the institutional education of physics 'jump in', ... without spending too much time describing and relating the more fundamental concepts that give rise to all these details". This is why so many students, and even researchers on all the levels, feel confused about all sort of concepts. (That includes myself)

Comment: The latter half of this is very opinion-based. In my opinion.

Comment: Physics is fundamentally *descriptive*. It's about learning to predict what "what would happen if ...". It's not in the business of defining what stuff is or is not, just how it works. And I know that sounds very limited and unhelpful, but it *works*.

Comment: The odd thing isn't that we don't start with definitions, but that the descriptive approach leads (eventually) to a pretty deep understanding of the underlying nature of *stuff*.

Comment: @ACuriousMind - that's the point of my question. I'm asking the more experienced physicists on this forum to help me define it. Before we talk about force, momentum, angular momentum, electromagnetism ... etc. there are more fundaental 'stuff', 'things' or 'concepts' one should firmly have in their grasp, right? What are these things - what do we know about them, and what do we not know?

Comment: The latter half is not opinion, but rather my present belief - which may be false because of my gaps in education.

Comment: *"Before we talk about force, momentum, angular momentum, electromagnetism ... etc. there are more fundaental 'stuff', 'things' or 'concepts' one should firmly have in their grasp, right?"* That sounds logical, but you have to bootstrap the process first. You have to understand these thing as applied to everyday object before the deep description will help much. Or at least that is the philosophy that underlies the historical teaching strategies of physics.

Comment: I agree the ability to predict the outcome of a physical system is very often useful. But understanding why the data fits our models is much more; a fulfilling enterprise. The more interesting aspects of physics are the stuff we can't seem to get a firm handle on like time space and energy. Feynman wrote in his lectures "we don't know what energy is - only that it's this thing that's conserved". That was in the 1960's and I don't believe that's changed. Yes that's my opinion, and I don't see how to reword my post.

Comment: docscience, this question strays from physics into metaphysics.  If there were a metaphysics SE site, it would be an appropriate question but your question is 'out of scope' here.  That doesn't mean that your question isn't important or not worth considering.  It's just this isn't the proper place to ask it.

Comment: @docscience *The latter half is not opinion, but rather my present belief - which may be false...* I believe that marks the definition of opinion. But let's look it up: opinion - noun. A view or judgment formed about something, not necessarily based on fact or knowledge. Synonym #1: belief